# Caption alignment using left marginpar

Tags: floats, captions

I have some figures in my document aligned left in the margin and some figures in the body. When I want to put captions beneath them, there are some difficulties.

I tried to define a `floatsetup` to align the caption under the figure also left aligned with the `marginpar`. However if I do this the figure moves even further to the left. And also the figures who are aligned in the text body are affected (want to keep their caption in the body).

So can someone tell me:

- How to align the caption text in the left `marginpar`, keeping the figure also aligned in the margin par
- Define a separate `floatsetup` for figures left aligned in the margin part and figures in the body part, however, use the figure environment for both types of figures.

See my MWE and some added images of the wrong situation, one can go back to the original situation by disabling the `floatsetup[figure]`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
includemp,
            showframe,
            reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}   % Correctly placed anchors for hyperlinks
\usepackage{floatrow}               % Set up captions of floats
\usepackage{chngpage}              % to adjust the width      

\floatsetup[figure]{margins=hangleft}
\setcapindent{0pt}


\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]                                         
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}{}
\noindent\includegraphics[height=6cm]{blackbox}
\caption{example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part 
 example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example 
 for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for 
 overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull 
 hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox 
 when aligning figure in leftmargin part}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering                                        
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{blackbox}
\caption{example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part 
example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example 
for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for 
overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull 
hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when 
aligning figure in leftmargin part}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest the figure environment inside `adjustwidth`, not the contrary, and add `\raggedright` command before inserting the graphic file.
Note that `chngpage` is obsolete, and should be replaced with `changepage`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
            includemp,
            showframe,verbose,
             reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,%
            hmargin = 2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}%[demo]
\usepackage{caption} % Correctly placed anchors for hyperlinks
\usepackage{floatrow} % Set up captions of floats
\usepackage{changepage} % to adjust the width

\floatsetup[figure]{margins=hangleft}
\setcapindent{0pt}

%
\makeatletter % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother
\newlength{\adjmargin}
\setlength{\adjmargin}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-\adjmargin}{}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \raggedright\includegraphics[height=6cm]{Nightmare_Fussli}
    \caption{example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part
      example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example
      for overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for
      overfull hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull
      hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox
      when aligning figure in leftmargin part}
  \end{figure}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One small thing. This example I made to use it in the end for a figure using an 'tabular environment' to place two figure next to eachother. However if I do this I get an error.

{File ended while scanning use of \caption@xdblarg}

Any Idea?

Comment: Or is it more convenient to make a new question including a MWE?

Comment: @Sleenders: Could you explain  shols be the captions in case of two (or more) figures? Also are they independent figures or subfigures?

Comment: I posted a new question including the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use different setup for `figure` environment with `floatrow` by setting values for `widefigure` and using `figure*` environment for special figures.  Maybe this is a starting point for you:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  includemp            ,
  showframe            ,
  verbose              ,
  reversemp            ,
  paperwidth=20.1cm    ,
  paperheight=25.80cm  ,
  top=2.30cm           ,
  bottom=3.4cm         ,
  hmargin = 2.7cm      ,
  marginparwidth=1.6cm ,
  marginparsep=0.4cm
}

\usepackage{floatrow,graphicx}

\floatsetup[figure]{%
  heightadjust      = all            ,
  margins           = raggedright    ,
  captionskip       = 10pt           ,
  capposition       = bottom         ,
  objectset         = centering      ,
  capbesideposition = {right,bottom} ,
  valign            = t
}

\floatsetup[widefigure]{%
  margins        = hangleft        ,
  objectset      = raggedright     ,
  capbesidewidth = \marginparwidth ,
  captionskip    = 7pt             ,
  floatwidth     = \textwidth}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{%
  font      = footnotesize,
  labelfont = {sf,bf}}

\captionsetup[figure]{%
  format        = plain      ,
  justification = centerlast ,
  labelsep      = quad
}

\captionsetup[widefigure]{%
  width=\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\makeatletter % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-1x1}%
  }{%
    \caption{example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
      leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure
      in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning
      figure in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when
      aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull hbox
      when aligning figure in leftmargin part example for overfull
      hbox when aligning figure in leftmargin part}%
  }%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-16x9}
  \caption{example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part example for overfull hbox when aligning figure in
    leftmargin part}%
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Also works, but for simplicity used the one below.